# How do I send a modal after a deferred button call in Pycord?

Tags: python, pycord

I'm trying to defer a button call and then send a modal afterward in Pycord. Here's a portion of my code:

```py
class AddItemButton(Button):  # Button class from discord.ui.Button
    def __init__(self, title):
        super().__init__(style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, label="Add Item", emoji="➕")
        self.title = title  # Title is just something from the database to access things

    async def callback(self, interaction):
        await interaction.response.defer()  # Defer the call
        # -- Add deletion if there's one or more items in the database --
        fetch_one = itemsExistInList(title=self.title, user_id=interaction.user.id)

        if fetch_one and self.view.get_item("delete"):
            self.view.add_item(ItemDeleteSelect(title=self.title, user_id=interaction.user.id))

        await self.view.message.edit(view=self.view)
        await interaction.response.send_modal(AddItemModal(message=self.view.message, title=self.title))  
        # ^ Attempt a response
```

Specifically this portion:

```
await interaction.response.send_modal(AddItemModal(message=self.view.message, title=self.title))
```

When I try the above, I get the following error:

```
discord.errors.InteractionResponded: This interaction has already been responded to before
```

Because the interaction has already been responded to, I decided to use a followup. A followup in Pycord is:

> Returns the followup webhook for followup interactions.

When I attempted to exchange the previous line with:

```py
        await interaction.followup.send_modal(AddItemModal(message=self.view.message, title=self.title))
```

It returned:

```py
    await interaction.followup.send_modal(AddItemModal(message=self.view.message, title=self.title))
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Webhook' object has no attribute 'send_modal'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, it turns out you can't send a modal after a button defer. This is because Pycord's followup returns a `Webhook` object which:
[image: Webhook params]

See [here](https://docs.pycord.dev/en/stable/api/webhooks.html#discord.Webhook)

---

This means you can't send a modal through the webhook. The solution to this is to **not** defer the webhook. Code:

````py
class AddItemButton(Button):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super().__init__(style=discord.ButtonStyle.blurple, label="Add Item", emoji="➕")
        self.title = title

    async def callback(self, interaction):
        await interaction.response.send_modal(AddItemModal(message=self.view.message, title=self.title))


        await self.view.message.edit(view=self.view)```
````